# TSQL deleting rows not in top(5) with key over 3 columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a table with a key on the columns `EventTimeStamp`, `UserID` and `SecurityEventCode`.

I want to delete all rows except the 5 newest.

```
DELETE 
FROM dbo.UsersSecurityEvents
WHERE  
    EventTimeStamp NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@maxSecurityEventByUser)
                               EventTimeStamp, UserID, SecurityEventCode
                           FROM dbo.UsersSecurityEvents
                           ORDER BY EventTimeStamp)
```

Now the question: how to get the values `UserID` and `SecurityEventCode` into the where clause? Do I need to use a cursor? I use most of the time Entity Framework for my SQL, but need to make changes to an old application.

Thank you for the help.

**SOLVED**

I was too stupid. I have a parameter `@UserID`.

So

```
    DELETE 
    FROM dbo.UsersSecurityEvents
    WHERE  
        UserID = @UserID 
        AND EventTimeStamp NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@maxSecurityEventByUser)
                                       EventTimeStamp
                                   FROM dbo.UsersSecurityEvents
                                   ORDER BY EventTimeStamp)
```

is the solution.

Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: How does `UserID` & `SecurityEventCode` come into play here? why are they in the query at all?

Comment: EventTimeStamp, UserID and SecurityEventCode are the primary key. I can have the same timestamp in different rows. Its a big application, 7 server behind a loadbalancer and over 500000 logins per day. So there is the possibility to get the same timestamp for different users.

Comment: Can you show a short sample of before and after (what data you expect, and how you expect it to be transformed)?

Comment: What do you mean with transformed? Its simple, It is a composite primary key.

Comment: Suppose you have some data, lets say it's a very long list of numbers, that you only want the even numbers to remain. Then you'd say: My list looks like "1, 2, 3, 6, 203, 56, 4, ..." and I want the result to be "2, 6, 56, 4, ...". But you do that with your type of data, and you make sure the sample includes relevant edge cases.

Comment: Before I have 6 Rows and after the delete I want to have 5 rows. Oh no, I am an idiot. I have to check the UserID. Shame over me, i need to add where UserID = @UserID AND EventTimeStamp NOT IN....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELETE FROM
 dbo.UsersSecurityEvents WHERE
 EventTimeStamp NOT IN ( 
     SELECT Top 5  EventTimeStamp
     FROM dbo.UsersSecurityEvents 
     ORDER BY EventTimeStamp desc
)
```

Comment: I need to check the UserID too. All 3 fields are the primary key, so i have to check them all. I could make the SecurityEventCode as fk, but UserID and EventTimeStamp have to be my primary key. TimeStamp is not unique.

Comment: @Sardoan How will tell which of the rows are newest? by EventTimeStamp ONLY correct? Praveen: the order should be descending.

Comment: Thanks. I had a brainfreeze. But thanks for the hint with desc.